# Linux tells me a serial port is in use, but it isn't

Tags: linux, serial-port

On CrunchBang linux (Debian variant), I have a COM port on `ttyS0`, which I'm trying to use with an NFC device. libnfc responded that it couldn't see any NFC devices, so I tried directly opening the COM port. For this, I used:

```
sudo cu -l /dev/ttyS0 -s 9600
```

However, this command returns:

```
cu: open (/dev/ttyS0): Permission denied
cu: /dev/ttyS0: Line in use
```

I don't know what could possibly be using this connection. To find out, I've tried reading all open processes and filtering for the use of `ttyS0`:

```
ps -ef | grep tty
```

but for this command, nothing shows up that is using `ttyS0`. I've also tried grabbing all open files and filtering for a lock on `ttyS0`:

```
lsof | grep tty
```

but this returns nothing using `ttyS0`.

How is it possible the `cu` says the line is in use, but both `ps` and `lsof` return nothing using that line?

Comment: What about lsof /dev/ttyS0

Comment: @Ciclamino That doesn't change it - tty is a substring of `/dev/ttyS0`. That does, however, hide all the other ttys.

Comment: I have the same problem. `minicom` works fine, but `cu` and `screen` refuse to talk to `/dev/ttyUSB0`. I was advised to add my user to the `uucp` and `dialout` groups and log out that didn't help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is probably no real usage of the line, but a permission issue.
quick and dirty way to test for me was to execute:

```
ls -la /dev/ttyUSB0
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and retry `cu`. If it starts working, you need to take care of the respective `udev` file and the user permissions/groups. For my device it looked like this (being member in `plugdev` group):

```
> cat /etc/udev/rules.d/42-CP210x.rules 
ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",
ACTION=="add", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Comment: I had this issue with ser2net, it just responded ´Device open failure: Object was already in use` and the root cause was the permissions.

Answer (score 5):

Serial devices privileges are granted to members of the `dialout` group. To get connected to `/dev/ttyS0` I added the current user to the group using:

`sudo adduser <username> dialout`

Comment: `sudo: adduser: command not found`

Comment: It should be noted, that it is neccessary to re-login after being added to the dialout group. An already running process is not aware that the current user has been added to a annother group.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this is a bug in `cu`. I solved this by changing owner group of `/dev/ttyUSB0` using following command:

```
chown root:root /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: `chown: root: illegal group name`

Answer (score 0):

Add your user to the `dialout` group. Depending on the system, it may also be necessary to add your user to the `uucp` group.

Check the group for membership:

```bsh
getent group dialout
```

Or check your user:

```bsh
groups `whoami`
```

Add your user if necessary:

```bsh
usermod -aG dialout `whoami`
```

verify with `getent` as mentioned above.